# Storybook 6, use module paths?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webkit, storybook, sass-loader

Is it possible to configure storybook 6 to use the module paths in my tsconfig.json file to work with `sass-loader` (or just to replicate the same pattern if that's not possible).

Ideally, I'd like to be able to add a sass loader with this option:

```
additionalData: `
  @use '@themes' as vars;
  @use '@themes/breakpoints' as bp;
`,
```

instead of

```
additionalData: `
  @use '../themes' as vars;
  @use '../themes/breakpoints' as bp;
`,
```

My `tsconfig.json` file has this section in it which works well inside .ts files but obviously doesn't work in sass files:

```
"paths": {
      "@components/*": ["./components/*"]
    }
```

If I could replicate that for themes, that'd be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, past Alex, there is a better solution now using the [ts-config-paths-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin) that is automatic and doesn't require repeating config code:

```js
// main.js

const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

const pathsPlugin = new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
  configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, '../tsconfig.json')
})

webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    if (config.resolve.plugins) {
      config.resolve.plugins.push(pathsPlugin);
    } else {
      config.resolve.plugins = [pathsPlugin];
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was pretty easy:

in `main.js`. Add the following to your module.exports:

```
webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
 config.resolve.alias = {
    ...config.resolve.alias,
    "@themes": path.resolve(__dirname, "../themes/default")
  }
  return config;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, past me. I just came up against this issue again and found myself!

Comment: For whatever reason, the solution to use `TsconfigPathsPlugin` resulted in endless loading of Storybook. This solution worked instead.